# Не хочет работать turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle

При импорте `turtle` выдает ошибки. Делаю точь в точь как другие, но у меня не хочет работать.

Вот код:

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
```

А вот что выдает строка:

```
C:turtle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "C:turtle.py", line 3, in <module>
    from turtle import Screen
ImportError: cannot import name 'Screen' from partially initialized module 'turt
le' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:turtle.py)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переименуйте свой файл `turtle.py` в другой, например `turtle_test.py`

При импортировании `from turtle import Screen` поиск сначала был в текущей папке, а там был ваш файл `turtle.py`, что привело к цикличному импортированию